# Can't read the same file from an Input tag twice using getElemenById + FileReader API

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, input

Currently, I'm developing a WebService which user selects a file and we're doing some pre-processing on user's browser later we will send the file to the server.

When a user selects a file from file manager(`<input type=file id="dropzone"/>`) an event will fire and will load the selected file using FileReaderAPI, when the process is done(it's guaranteed that this section will execute after the first process finished) when I want to read the file again later in the service using `document.getElementById("dropzone")` it returns the `null`.

here is the code for the input component, in this case, I'm using react-dropzone.js:(since I'm accessing input element by `getElementById` it makes no difference which library is used)

```
const{
    acceptedFiles
  } = useDropzone({
    accept: "video/*, .mkv",
    onDrop: files => props.handle()
  });

return(<div> <input {...getInputProps()} id="dropzone"/> </div>) ;
```

`props.handle(files)` refer to the function which will be doing the file processing

following is a part of `handle()` function which deals with the selected file and will fire when a user selects a file.

```
    var upFile = document.getElementById("dropzone");
    var file = upFile.files[0];

 //Original function iterate over all slices
      var r = new FileReader();
      var blob = file.slice(offset, length + offset);
      r.onload = processChunk;
      r.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);
```

Later when I want to access the file again using `document.getElementById("dropzone")` it returns `null`

Any Idea for solving this?

Comment: Why reading the uploaded files from `document`? Why not reading them from the `acceptedFiles`?

Comment: because it's in a different component( nested component)

Comment: You can pass the file up or down through the component tree, it doesn't matter if it is another component, or you can use state management libraries or sth like that. Right?

Comment: Yeah, that's completely right but it's in 2 components up, not very practical by doing so ... but the main question is totally different whether my approach or yours, both should be working

Comment: Can you create a reproducible example? So that it is more clear? I'm trying to duplicate your problem but it just works fine with me.

Comment: do you load the entire file using the FileReader ?(e.g. filereader.readAsArrayBuffer(wholefile) ;)

Comment: Yeah, it just works fine, the file is still stored in the input and is still accessible via document.

Comment: A small codepen/codesandbox example would do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many trials and errors, I found out this is caused by one of the browser's 3rd party security extensions.

**Make sure to disable these kinds of extensions in the developing stage.**